# Getting rid of empty elements in a list

Tags: python, list, astropy

I am working with astropy and I am at a point where I printed `Data` and got the following result as my output:

```
[<MaskedColumn name='phot_bp_rp_excess_factor' dtype='float32' description='BP/RP excess factor' length=1>
4.678),                                       
(<MaskedColumn name='phot_bp_rp_excess_factor' dtype='float32' description='BP/RP excess factor' length=0>], 
(<MaskedColumn name='phot_bp_rp_excess_factor' dtype='float32' description='BP/RP excess factor' length=1>
9.876)]
```

So now I am trying to put "BP/RP excess factor" in a new list `x`, so I tried:

```
x=[]
for i in data:  
    if bp > 0:
    x.append(bp[-1]) # "[-1]" to get rid of text and just print out the numbers 
#I am expecting [4.678,9.876]
```

But this gives me an error saying `index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`. I know this problems exist because in my output above I have `length=0`, but I dont know to write a code that ignores if `"length=0"` and gives me a list of numbers for elements that have `"length=1"`.

Comment: In the future if you can also provide setup code so that answerers can copy/paste your example and run it themselves, you'll make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Try `if bp.length > 0` or `if len(bp) > 0`

Comment: `if bp.size > 0`

Comment: How did you end up with a list of `MaskedColumn` all with the same name to begin with?  It's hard to say, but I think you might have made your life harder in some other way, but earlier on in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with astropy, but filtering on the length of `data` seems to work in my local testing:

```
from astropy.table import MaskedColumn

In [16]: columns = [
    ...:     MaskedColumn(data=[1]),
    ...:     MaskedColumn(data=[]),
    ...:     MaskedColumn(data=[2,3])
    ...: ]

In [17]: not_empty = [col for col in columns if len(col.data) > 0]

In [18]: not_empty
Out[18]:
[<MaskedColumn dtype='int64' length=1>
 1,
 <MaskedColumn dtype='int64' length=2>
 2
 3]

In [19]: len(not_empty)
Out[19]: 2
```

Edit:

`column.size` also works, thanks to @python_user in the comments:

```
not_empty = [col for col in columns if col.size > 0]
```